# Why doesn't my Perl script use my module?

Tags: perl, perl-module, subroutine

module.pm

```
package module;
use 5.012;
use warnings;

sub Parse
{
   return 1;
}

1;
```

script.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use 5.012;
use warnings;
use lib 'C:/';
use module;

print Parse("value");
```

Stdout

```
Undefined subroutine &main::Parse
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need either to write:

```
print module::Parse("value");
```

or to change the `module` package to export the name `Parse`.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules for guidance in exporting symbols from your module.

(By the way, you should really name your module `Module` rather than `module`. Lowercase module-names are used for Perl built-in features like `use warnings` and `use strict`.)

Comment: or don't specify a different package in module.pm

Comment: @evilotto: Oh, yes, that's true . . . but that's too evil for me to even want to mention it. :-P

Comment: I added `use Exporter; @ISA = qw(Parse);`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @EricFossu: `@ISA` ("is-a") is for specifying a superclass. You mean `@ISA = qw(Exporter); @EXPORT = qw(Parse);`.

Comment: I hate Exporter's crappy API. It confuses the everlasting heck out of the beginners. [Sub::Exporter](http://p3rl.org/Sub::Exporter::Tutorial) is a saner alternative.

Comment: Finally got it. `use Exporter ();
our (@ISA, @EXPORT);
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(&Parse);`

Comment: @Eric: That will work, but putting the '&' in front of the name is pretty non-standard.

Comment: @evil otto, That's very bad advice.

Comment: @ikegami - no argument there.  But it is correct.  And better that someone suggests it and others point out why it's bad than having he novice discover it on their own.  Also, were it good advice I would have made it its own answer.

Comment: @evil otto, It is not correct. Not only is it a bad design, one would have to change `use` to `do` for it to work properly.

Comment: @ikegami - you and I must have different definitions of "correct".  I'm using it in the sense of "works; causes the OP's code to return the expected results."  In that sense, my suggestion works (unless more recent versions of perl have done something insane and incompatible to the way that "use" works.)

Comment: @evil otto, Again, no, it doesn't work. the former module needs to be executed by every would be importer, but using `require` or `use` means only the first will execute the script.

Comment: @ikegami again no, you're wrong, because what I said works in the case the question posed.  If you would like to explain more fully why you consider my answer wrong and not merely a "not best practice", please do - it would be much more educational than just claiming it doesn't work.  I'll be impressed (and educated) if you can give an example of it not working that doesn't involve either another file beyond the OP's original 2, or using multiple packages within a single file.

Comment: @evil motto, I am talking about the posted code. Code that uses the OP's module, as posted but without the `package` can fail. Again, telling someone to remove the package is very bad advice. It is incorrect, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Several things:

- First, use `Local` as your module prefix. That way, if you just happen to have a module with the same name in your Perl installation, it will use yours. Call it "Local::Module". Then, create a `Local` directory, and name your module `Module.pm`.
- The other thing you have to understand is that you define your module in another *namespace*. By default, everything is in the `main` namespace until you use the `package` statement. That creates another *namespace* that your package uses. This way, if your package has a function `foo`, and you've defined a function `foo` in your main program, they won't collide.

Thus, you have two choices: One (the preferred now) is to simply call your subroutine with the full package name prepended to it. The second is to export your subroutine names to your main program. This can cause problems with duplicate names, but you don't have to keep typing in the package name every time you call your subroutine.

### Without Exporting the name

#### Local/Module.pm

```
# /usr/bin/env perl
# Local/Module.pm
package Local::Module;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub Parse {
    my $value = shift;  #Might as well get it.

    print "I got a value of $value\n";
    return $value;
}
1;    #Need this or the module won't load
```

#### program.pl

```
# /usr/bin/env perl
# program.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Local::Module;

Local::Module::Parse("Foo");
```

---

### With export:

#### Local/Module.pm

```
# /usr/bin/env perl
# Local/Module.pm
package Local::Module;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK(Parse);   #Allows you to export this name into your main program

sub Parse {
    my $value = shift;  #Might as well get it.

    print "I got a value of $value\n";
    return $value;
}
1;    #Need this or the module won't load
```

#### program.pl

```
# /usr/bin/env perl
# program.pl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Local::Module qw(Parse);

Parse("Foo");
```